# Property injection into custom WebViewPage using Autofac

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autofac

I'm creating an internal application framework that other dev teams in our organisation will use to build MVC applications from. As part of that, I'm creating the menu structure for all views, that is read from configuration and modified based on the current user's permissions. To create the menu as part of the framework, I've created a custom `WebViewPage` implementation with a custom HTML Helper class that needs to take a dependency on an `ApplicationDataReader` to construct the menu.

I've read various posts that explain that MVC needs the `WebViewPage` to have a paramterless constructor, so I would need to use property injection. I've configured [Autofac MVC3 Integration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration3), including registering a `ViewRegistrationSource`. Trouble is, when the dependent property is accessed, it's always null.

Here's the custom view page and helper with the call I'm trying to make:

```
public abstract class OuBaseViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel> where TModel : class
{
    public OuHelper<TModel> Ou { get; set; }

    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        base.InitHelpers();
        Ou = new OuHelper<TModel>(ViewContext, this);
    }
}

public class OuHelper<TModel> where TModel : class
{
    public OuHelper(ViewContext viewContext, IViewDataContainer viewDataContainer)
        : this(viewContext, viewDataContainer, RouteTable.Routes)
    {
    }

    public OuHelper(ViewContext viewContext, IViewDataContainer viewDataContainer, RouteCollection routeCollection)
    {
        ViewContext = viewContext;
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(viewDataContainer.ViewData);
    }

    public ViewDataDictionary<TModel> ViewData { get; private set; }

    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; private set; }

    public IList<BusinessFocusArea> ReadFocusAreas()
    {
        // this is null - yes, service location, but an isolated instance of...
        return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IDataReader>().Read();
    }
}
```

The problem stems from the fact that `InitHelpers` is being called (via `Layout.Execute()`) BEFORE `Application_Start` is called, so none of the dependencies have been registered. I know that it's not good practice to inject logic into views and that views should simply be dumb, but this is an application framework and it needs to perform certain setup steps that the developers using the framework mustn't have visibility of.

**Is there a better approach I could follow?**

There's a similar issue here: [Can Autofac inject dependencies into layout view files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593580/can-autofac-inject-dependencies-into-layout-view-files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem stems from the fact that InitHelpers is being called (via
>   Layout.Execute()) BEFORE Application_Start is called

I don't think that something is called before `Application_Start`. I cannot reproduce your problem.

Here are the steps I did and which worked perfectly fine:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the Internet Template
2. Install the `Autofac.Mvc3` NuGet
3. Define a dummy interface:

   ```
   public interface IDataReader
   {

   }
   ```
4. And a dummy implementation:

   ```
   public class DataReader : IDataReader
   {

   }
   ```
5. Define a custom helper:

   ```
   public class OuHelper<TModel> where TModel : class
   {
       private readonly IDataReader dataReader;
       public OuHelper(ViewContext viewContext, IViewDataContainer viewDataContainer, IDataReader dataReader)
           : this(viewContext, viewDataContainer, RouteTable.Routes, dataReader)
       {
       }

       public OuHelper(ViewContext viewContext, IViewDataContainer viewDataContainer, RouteCollection routeCollection, IDataReader dataReader)
       {
           ViewContext = viewContext;
           ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(viewDataContainer.ViewData);
           this.dataReader = dataReader;
       }

       public ViewDataDictionary<TModel> ViewData { get; private set; }

       public ViewContext ViewContext { get; private set; }

       public IDataReader DataReader
       {
           get { return this.dataReader; }
       }

   }
   ```
6. Define a custom WebViewPage using this helper:

   ```
   public abstract class OuBaseViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel> where TModel : class
   {
       public OuHelper<TModel> Ou { get; set; }

       public override void InitHelpers()
       {
           base.InitHelpers();
           var dataReader = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IDataReader>();
           Ou = new OuHelper<TModel>(ViewContext, this, dataReader);
       }
   }
   ```
7. Replace the default view page with the custom one in `~/Views/web.config`:

   ```
   <pages pageBaseType="MvcApplication1.OuBaseViewPage">
   ```
8. Configure your container in `Application_Start`:

   ```
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
       AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
       RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
       RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

       var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
       builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
       builder.RegisterType<DataReader>().As<IDataReader>();
       var container = builder.Build();
       DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
   }
   ```
9. Now you could happily use the custom helper in all views including the _Layout without any problems:

   ```
   @Ou.DataReader.GetType()
   ```

Of course in this example I have just exposed the `IDataReader` dependency as a public property to illustrate you that it will always be injected and it will never be null. In your particular code you could of course use only the private readonly field inside the helper to achieve your task.

Comment: Thanks Darin - that's pretty much what I've done but `Application_Start` is not firing for me. Once I get to the bottom of why that is, the rest should work fine...

Comment: Sorted. The problem was that I hadn't considered the fact that the `Application_Start` method in my framework won't fire because the `Application_Start` method in the application that uses the framework fires instead. We're using Web Activator for precisely this reason, so I can hook up all the dependencies through Web Activator via a `PostApplicationStartMethod` hook and bin the Global.asax file from the framework to avoid this confusion in the future! Thanks for highlighting that my logic should work

Comment: This method forces us to use service location. Previously, I had been successful decorating a property in the WebViewPage<T> subclass with Dependency attribute (this is Unity - not AutoFac) but I had to use your approach in order to use it in the layout.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, I am not going to change my implementation now but do you think it might have been useful to use ambient context pattern instead of service location in this case? The dependency, judging by its name, looks like it only reads stuff. If it would be a cross-cutting concern, which I don't know, it might have been a preferable way to user service location. Would it not?