# Property Injection with AutoFac in Base controller mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

I am working with ASP.net MVC app. where I want to inject service in base controller class (I can not use Constructor injection for DI).

I want to use property injection in base controller.

following are service code:

```
 public interface IUserService {}
 public class UserService : IUserService
 {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        private readonly IUserRepository userRepo;
        private readonly ILoginAttemptRepository loginAttemptRepo;
        private readonly IRoleRepository roleRepository;
        public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository, 
            ILoginAttemptRepository loginAttemptRepository,
            IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IRoleRepository roleRepository)
        {
            userRepo = userRepository;
            this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            loginAttemptRepo = loginAttemptRepository;
            this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        }
 }
```

following are Autoface global setup:

```
private static void SetAutofacContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // MVC - Register your MVC controllers.
            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<DatabaseFactory>().As<IDatabaseFactory>().InstancePerRequest();

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(BankRepository).Assembly)
           .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
           .AsImplementedInterfaces()
           .InstancePerRequest();

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(UserService).Assembly)
           .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
           .AsImplementedInterfaces()
           .InstancePerRequest();

            // Register for filter 
            builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

            //Register for base class
            // builder.RegisterType<IUserService>().PropertiesAutowired();

            // MVC - Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
            var container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        }
```

Base controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller  
 {
    public IUserService UserService { get; set; }

    //todo: using UserService instance 
 }
```

I tried using  **builder.RegisterType().PropertiesAutowired();**
but it did not worked , Any Idea what I am missing or how can I achieve this ?

Comment: can you show base controller code ?

Comment: The properties need to be autowired on the controllers, not the userservice.  Did you try it on your `RegisterControllers` line?

Comment: @stephen.vakil can u share some ref, I m not clear what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly)
       .PropertiesAutowired();
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29536104/3264939